# URL mapping problems using Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml, url-mapping

I have a very basic setup which I am trying to get working.

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/site/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blabla.controller" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp"
    p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
```

**In the controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/site")
public class SearchController {

@RequestMapping(value = "welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {
       return "test";
    }
```

This is the problem that I have:
I would like to write **/site/*** as url-pattern in my web.xml, but when I do that I get

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/site/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

When I write **/site/welcome** in full, everything works, but I dont want this because I dont want to add every page manually to the web.xml

And when I write  **"/*"**  as url-pattern i get the error message:

```
 WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/test.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

which I guess makes sense because the the location of the jsp is included in the pattern.

So how do you do it: how can you be sufficiently vague in your url pattern without the problems I just had?

Comment: In your web.xml, I think you need to set the servlet-mapping url-pattern to /.  Otherwise, I think your controller would be mapped to /site/site/welcome.

Comment: that does work. Thank you. But I would still rather use the /site/* mapping. Do you also know why that won't work for me ?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it now. I needed to get rid of the requestMapping on the class of my controller and then the /site/* mapping in web.xml does work.

Comment: That is the other option, but now you are stuck with one controller handling all your site mappings.  Might not be bad if you have a small application, but could cause problems if your controller code gets out of hand.